# Determine all prime numbers $p,q,r$ such that : $p^{2}+1=r^{2}+q^{2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Problem :

find all prime numbers such that :

> $$p^{2}+1=q^{2}+r^{2}$$

My attempt :

equation equivalent :

$p^{2}-q^{2}=r^{2}-1$

so :

$(p+q)(p-q)=(r+1)(r-1)$

now :

$r=2$ we find : $p+q=2$ or $p-q=1$ $×$

$r=3$ we find : $p+q=3,2$ or $p-q=2,3$ $×$

$r=5$ we find : $p+q=10,2,4,5,20$ or $p-q=2,20,10,5,4,$

so I have many case how I find it ?

see :

$13^{2}+1=7^{2}+11^{2}$

$17^{2}+1=11^{2}+13^{2}$

$23^{2}+1=13^{2}+19^{2}$

$31^{2}+1=11^{2}+29^{2}$

I need generalized this solution ? 
I think ?

$(5x+13)^{2}+1=(3x+7)^{2}+(4x+11)^{2}$

I think we have infinity prime numbers

but how I prove it ? and how I find this case ??

Comment: What is $x$ in your second solution?

Comment: $(3x+7)^2+(4x+11)^2=9x^2+42x+49+16x^2+88x+121=25x^2+130x+170=(5x+13)^2+1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner can you explain how we find $p,q,r$ by try ??

Comment: $7^2+1=5^2+5^2$ and cf. [sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.- One way could be to consider the general solution of the equation  $x^ 2 + y^ 2 = z^ 2 + w^ 2$ that gives a parameterization with four independent  coprime parameters with which one could look for prime values  for $r$ and $q$. For example by making $at-bs = 1$ and $as + bt = p$, try to see if primes $r$ and $q$ are obtained with appropriate values of the parameters $a, b, t, r$. But this march is very laborious.

A curious fact is that for the (type Pell-Fermat) equation $p^2+1=2q^2$  (trying with $r=q$) all the infinitely many  integer solutions given by Wolfram does not appear the solution $(p,q)=(7,5)$ but it appears, for example $(p,q)=(41,29)$. Again this way is very laborious to find primes as solutions.

Anyway, it seems in fact as the O.P. suggests that there are an infinite number of solutions of which we give a few here.

$$7^2+1=5^2+5^2\\41^2+1=29^2+29^2\\13^2+1=7^2+11^2\\17^2+1=11^2+13^2\\23^2+1=13^2+19^2\\37^2+1=23^2+29^2\\47^2+1=29^2+37^2\\53^2+1=31^2+43^2$$

Comment: @Pqutio thank you very much , what can you say about generalized

Comment: Nothing really valid. What I imagine as "probably useful" is to assume for the absurd that there is a maximum prime for which there are solutions (that there are only a finite number of these) and hence try to find another greater prime. However, how to prove this seems difficult to me. Another way would be to find a parameterization but that such parameterization gives only prime numbers, it seems unrealizable (Note that I am assuming that there are an infinite number of solutions).